# Set Display resolution limit in unity

Tags: android, optimization, unity-game-engine, screen, device

So I released a game a few months ago.

I run a lot of test on devices I add at home (galaxy note 2, galaxy tab pro, wiko), and the game runs smoothly on these devices.

But last day, I run my game on an LG G3 device, and there are a lot of FPS drops.

I think it's because the game runs with the native display resolution of the screen (2560 x 1440).

Is it possible to create a script, that when it detects a display resolution upper than FullHD (like for the LG G3), it displays the game in a lower resolution?

I think it would stop the FPS drops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust same Camera Resolution on every Device.

If your Game is in portrait mode then use 720*1280 resolution and if using landscape mode the use 960*640 , your game will run perfect on every device.

1. Attach Script to your camera
2. Change Values targetaspect

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraResolution : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {
    // set the desired aspect ratio (the values in this example are
    // hard-coded for 16:9, but you could make them into public
    // variables instead so you can set them at design time)
    float targetaspect = 720.0f / 1280.0f;

    // determine the game window's current aspect ratio
    float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;

    // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount
    float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;

    // obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
    Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera> ();

    // if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
    if (scaleheight < 1.0f) {  
        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = 1.0f;
        rect.height = scaleheight;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;

        camera.rect = rect;
    } else { // add pillarbox
        float scalewidth = 1.0f / scaleheight;

        Rect rect = camera.rect;

        rect.width = scalewidth;
        rect.height = 1.0f;
        rect.x = (1.0f - scalewidth) / 2.0f;
        rect.y = 0;

        camera.rect = rect;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did you know that the script doesn't change the resolution?

Comment: Yes but its applicable to different resolutions. Its written for 1280/720 but you can see the code that it scales higher and lower resolutions accordingly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but i don't understand how can i downsize the resolution of my game to full HD if a device screen display have QHD or 4k screen? (because unity runs the game in the screen display resolution and it's very power consumption if the device has a 2k or more display).

Answer (score 1):

is not that easy (with a good quality result).

Basically, you can use asset bundle system for it and have double of your graphics in SD and HD formats. Unity supports it, it calls variants. Please find more information about Asset Bundles here:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager

Detection of screen resolution is easy. You can use `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` for it.

I know `Screen` class has a method `SetResolution` and this might do a thing for you without using an Asset Bundle system. I have never use it on my own.
Here is more about `Screen` class:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html

and concrete `SetResolution` method:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html

You can use `Camera.aspect` to get an aspect ratio of the screen as well:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-aspect.html